# How to remove dot(.) on String in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

**assets/images/Defect/icon-5.svg**

I need to get ***svg*** on above String

> example:
>
> **print(path);**
>
> *output only svg*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')).substring(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a function called `extension` in `package:path/path.dart` that will give you the extension of a file. If you want to remove the `.` from that extension you just need to replace it with an empty space, something like:

```
    import 'package:path/path.dart';

    String svg = extension("assets/images/Defect/icon-5.svg");
    svg = svg.replaceAll(".", "");
    print(svg);
```

Reference [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-path_path/extension.html)

Answer (score 3):

`path.split('.')[1]`

The documentation for the split function is [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/String/split.html)

Comment: This assumes that `.` doesn't appear anywhere else in the path.

Comment: Sure it's probably not the most scalable answer, but it's quick and efficient in this case ;)

Comment: You don't know what what the case is.  The string provided in the question is an example.  If you want to work for just the specific string in the question, it'd be much simpler and much more efficient to do `String getExtension() => 'svg';`, but that'd be silly.  Your answer would be better if you at least explained the caveats about using it; otherwise other people might follow your advice without understanding its limitations.

Comment: Thanks, it also can be: String ext = path?.split(".")?.last